# Publishing a poetry-managed python package with relative path dependencies

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I'm trying to come up with a solution to what seems like a pretty mundane task: develop a python package with relative dependencies, and then publish it to PyPI, however all tools I have found so far seem not to address this issue. What am I not seeing?

I'll use `poetry` in this example since that is the most complete solution I could find so far, but alternatives would be fine too.
The package structure is pretty similar to this

```
├── package_a/
│   ├── package_a/...
│   └── pyproject.toml
├── package_b/
│   ├── package_b/...
│   └── pyproject.toml
```

Now the thing is that `package_b` depends on `package_a`, and I'd like to use a relative dependency in `pacakge_a/pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "package_a"

packages = [
  { include = "package_a" },
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
package_b = { path = "../package_b", develop = true }
```

The goal here to be able to develop both `package_a` and `package_b` in parallel without having to continuously publish and reinstall since that is quite error prone.

And it works, until I try and publish the packages to PyPI, where the path dependencies are just copied in, and are now clearly unresolvable, because the repository path context is lost when publishing a dist bundle.

Is there a way to have poetry swap out the actual versions in the dependencies when publishing, or will I really need to do some `sed` magic to achieve this very common task?

Comment: You case seems to be similar to this. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629578/python-how-to-make-poetry-include-a-package-module-thats-not-on-a-subpath.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and not sure what the best solution is here. The other issue linked is not quite the same. This has to do with the fact that relative path dependencies are not resolvable when publishing.

Maybe workaround for the time being is to have duplicate dependencies, one normal, one marked as development, and have the version pinned, and just use some repo-level script to update everything at once (i.e., `sed` magic).